# SSRS Query DataSet return blank result

Tags: xml, wcf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My embedded query returns no results.
I am using with WCF framework.
This is my request:

```
 <Query>
    <Method Namespace="Server" Name="GetReportList">   
    <Parameters>
                 <Parameter Name="id" type="String">
               <DefaultValue>3</DefaultValue>
                 </Parameter>
                 <Parameter Name="num" type="String">
               <DefaultValue>51146</DefaultValue>
                 </Parameter>
           
     </Parameters>
    </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
   GetReportResponse{}/GetReportResult{}/diffgram{}/NewDataSet{}/Table1
   {              
    oneProperty,
    twoProperty
    }/Table2
    {
    oneProperty,
    twoProperty,
    threeProperty
    }

    </ElementPath>

    </Query>
```

`

And it's give me blank result.

What can I do?

Comment: You have a frontend and a backend.  The front end is a WCF HTTP client/server connection.  You backend is the connection from the server to the database.   We can tell absolutely nothing from the frontend code you posted.

Comment: Thanks, but i found the answer. when i read the xml i need to set the syntax like my request func name. like this:GetReportListResponse{}/GetReportListResult{}/diffgram{}/NewDataSet{}/Table1